# Looping in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I want to add the column ID_last to the table to the left below. The example table consists of two sequences of 6 and 8 rows. I need to deal with many sequences and unknown/infinite number of rows per sequence/loops per sequence. A sequence starts when ID is not in ID_new, and a sequence stops when ID_new is not in ID. I want to know the last ID_new of all IDs in a sequence (like in the table to the right).

How do I do this with SQL (oracle) ?

Help is much appreciated!

[image: See image of table :)]

Comment: Are you intending to implement this with only a SELECT and joins or a PL/SQL block with cursors and loops?

Comment: Can you give an example of loops and what the desired output would be for those?

Comment: I plan on implementing it in informatica powercenter (in the source qualifier maybe). The tool is not important though. Just want that new column ID_last

Comment: Is there another column to indicate the actual ordering of id? How do you know it should start from Id = 11? and end with id = 45 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Oracle 11gR2 or more recent, you could use a recursive query like this (assuming your table is called `tbl`):

```
with tbl2(id, id_new, id_last, lvl) as (
    select     id, id_new, id_new, 1 
    from       tbl
    union all
    select     tbl2.id, tbl2.id_new, tbl.id_new, tbl2.lvl+1 
    from       tbl2
    inner join tbl 
            on tbl.id = tbl2.id_last
)
select unique id, id_new, 
       first_value(id_last) over (partition by id, id_new order by lvl desc) id_last 
from   tbl2
```

This does not deal with loops (I did not get a reply to my comment about that).

Comment: This works, but is sub optimal as it does excessive work to find the answer.  It travels the same tree multiple times since each record is treated as a tree root to find it's leaf node.  This generates a lot of extra data that then needs to be weeded through by your output queries unique operator.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last IDs in any sequence can be determined with this query:

```
select id_new from YourData yd
 where not exists (select 1 from YourData yd2
                    where yd2.id = yd.id_new);
```

We can treat the problem as a Hierarchical query rooted at the identified ID_Last values, returning the root ID as ID_Last:

```
select id
     , id_new
     , CONNECT_BY_ROOT id_new ID_Last
  from YourData yd
  connect by NOCYCLE id_new = prior id
 start with not exists (select 1 from YourData yd2
                         where yd2.id = yd.id_new)
```

Alternately this can be written as a recursive query, using the first query above (with additional columns) as the anchor query. To avoid cycles, we'll have to add a column to track the nodes that have already been visited, and check it in the recursive part of the query:

```
With Recur(id, id_new, id_last, nodes) as (
  select id
       , id_new
       , id_new
       , ':'||id||':'
    from YourData yd1
   where not exists (select 1 from YourData yd2
                      where yd2.id = yd1.id_new)
   union all
  select yd.id
       , yd.id_new
       , r.id_last
       , r.nodes||yd.id||':'
    from YourData yd
    join Recur r
      on r.id = yd.id_new
     and r.nodes not like '%:'||yd.id||':%' -- Avoid cycles
)
select id, id_new, id_last
  from Recur
 order by id_last
     , nodes desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a table name, so I'm assuming it's called **table1**.

Here's a query to find the leaf node for each node in your hierarchy. Note that you'll get some duplicates if any of your nodes have more than one child node.

```
-- sample data
with table1 as (select 11 as id, 12 as id_new from dual
    union all select 12, 5 from dual
    union all select 5, 18 from dual
    union all select 18, 17 from dual
    union all select 17, 28 from dual
    union all select 28, 13 from dual
    union all select 25, 31 from dual
    union all select 31, 22 from dual
    union all select 22, 41 from dual
    union all select 41, 33 from dual
    union all select 33, 39 from dual
    union all select 39, 30 from dual
    union all select 30, 45 from dual
    union all select 45, 24 from dual)
-- query
select regexp_substr(id_path, '[^>]+', 1, 1) as root, 
  id_new as id_last
from (select CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF isleaf, sys_connect_by_path(id, '>') as id_path, id_new
      from table1
      connect by prior id_new = id)
where isleaf = 1
;
```

I think this should work as an update statement, but I haven't tested it.

```
merge into table1 t
  using (select regexp_substr(id_path, '[^>]+', 1, 1) root, id_new as id_last
        from (select CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF isleaf, sys_connect_by_path(r.id, '>') as id_path, r.id_new
              from table1 r
              connect by prior r.id_new = r.id)
        where isleaf = 1) u
  on (t.id = u.root)
when matched then update
  set t.id_last = u.id_last;
```

Comment: This is an interesting take on the problem.  you could achieve your root determination more simply by using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` on ID instead of `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` (unless you are using Oracle 9i or earlier).  However, like @trincot you are traversing the same tree multiple times to achieve your answer, when once per tree would be sufficient.